# How does :class="`level ${file.invalidMessage && 'has-text-danger'}`" break down?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxgbgYtNzCw) to upload files using VueJS and Express server and I have encountered a line of code that I do not understand.

At 8:19 we are introduced to `` :class="`level ${file.invalidMessage && 'has-text-danger'}`" ``. I couldn't find anything similar in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes).

## Video Example:

```
<div v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="index"
:class="`level ${file.invalidMessage && 'has-text-danger'}`"
>

</div>
```

## Vue Docs:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
<div
  class="static"
  v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
></div>
<div v-bind:class="classObject"></div>
<div v-bind:class="[activeClass, errorClass]"></div>
<div v-bind:class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>
<div v-bind:class="[{ active: isActive }, errorClass]"></div>
```

There is nothing similar to that weird syntax in the Vue Documentation.
I understand what `${}` inside back quotes marks is used for(template literals).
I understand what the code purpose is, I have tested it and works, but I do not understand how it works and what shortcuts were used.

Can somebody "translate" that line of code ?

Comment: Actually I think the code is a bit lazy and not strictly correct with that `&&` shortcut, because if `file.invalidMessage` is `false` for example, then the class names will be `level false` (which may behave unexpectedly if you ever define a `false` class for another purpose!). `file.invalidMessage ? 'has-text-danger' : ''` would make more sense.

Comment: I have applied your suggestion on my code and it works just fine```:class="`file-line ${file.status ? 'wrong-file' : ''}`"```. But can you please explain his `&&` shortcut ?

Comment: `&&` is logical AND, it returns the first operand if it is falsy, otherwise it returns the second operand. So, `x && 'abc'` would evaluate to `'abc'` if `x` was a truthy value, but it would evaluate to `x`'s value if it was falsy. So `'xyz' && 'abc'` would become `'abc'` since `'xyz'` is truthy, but `0 && 'abc'` would become `0` (not an empty string as we need here) since `0` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

The `:class` binding in **Vue** accepts strings:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    classlist() {
      return this.classes.join(' ')
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      classes: [
        'first-class',
        'second-class'
      ],
      domClassList: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // getting and setting the classlist of the DOM element
    this.domClassList = document.getElementById('classList').getAttribute('class')
  }
})
```

```css
.level {
  background: green;
  padding: 15px;
}

.first-class {
  color: white;
}

.second-class {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="classList" :class="`level ${ classlist }`">
    CLASSES ADDED AS STRINGS
  </div>
  <div>Classes: {{ domClassList }}</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet above, the classes are made from one `level` and the join of a **Vue** `data` variable (the `classes` array) that is returned in a `computed` property (`classlist`).

The other part of the question is the conditional format:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    classlist() {
      return this.classes.join(' ')
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstOperand: true,
      classes: [
        'first-class',
        'second-class'
      ],
      domClassList: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setDomClassList() {
      // getting and setting the classlist of the DOM element
      this.domClassList = document.getElementById('classList').getAttribute('class')
    },
    toggleOperand() {
      this.firstOperand = !this.firstOperand
      // this.$nextTick is required so Vue can set the data
      // values before we read it from the DOM
      const self = this
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        self.setDomClassList()
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setDomClassList()
  }
})
```

```css
.level {
  background: green;
  padding: 15px;
}

.first-class {
  color: white;
}

.second-class {
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* this class is set so you can see the difference on
   toggling the firstOperand variable
*/

.false {
  font-style: italic
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="classList" :class="`level ${ firstOperand && classlist }`">
    CLASSES ADDED AS STRINGS
  </div>
  <div>Classes: {{ domClassList }}</div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    FIRSTOPERAND IS {{ firstOperand }}<br />
    <button @click="toggleOperand">TOGGLE FIRSTOPERAND TO {{ !firstOperand }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second snippet is almost the same as the first, except the `&&` is introduced. I also created a `.false` CSS value so you can see the returned **false**.